# Can I use tab to focus a p:inplace component so screenreader can read the element?

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces, accessibility

On my JSF page I have `p:inplace` after panelGrid. When using keyboard to navigate the page, tabbing completely skips the `p:inplace` component. How to get focus correctly on the component in such a way that a screenreader can read it in hierarchal way after a `panelGrid`?

Code snippet from the element:

```
              <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:outputLabel value="username"/> 
                <p:inputText label="username" value="#{sessVar.cust.username}" pt:aria-label="#{ss.username}" /> 
                 ...
              </h:panelGrid>
       
         <p:inplace editor="true" label="Change password" cancelLabel="Cancel">
                    <p:password id="oldpassword"
                                value="#{myBean.cust.oldPwd}"
                                placeholder="#{ss.oldPwd}"/>
                    <p:password id="password" 
                                value="#{sessVar.cust.newPwd}"
                                match="passwordconfirmation"
                                placeholder="#{ss.salasana}"/>
                    <p:password id="passwordconfirmation" 
                                value="#{sessVar.cust.conPwd}" 
                                placeholder="#{ss.confirmationPwd}"/>
                  </p:inplace>
```

Tried with @Jasper de Vries's solution:

```
         <p:inplace editor="true" label="Change password" cancelLabel="Cancel">
                <span tabindex="0"
                      onkeydown="if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                            PF('myInplace').display.trigger('click');
                            event.preventDefault()
                          }">
                  <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <p:password .../>
                    <p:password ...>
                    </p:password> 
                    <p:password .../>
                  </h:panelGrid>
                </span>
          </p:inplace>
```

Still no dice. Tabbing doesn't focus on `p:inplace` component.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: No luck. Decided to discard `p:inplace` completely.

Comment: That's weird.. I've tested the posted solution with the primefaces-test repo, and it is working for me. What error are you getting?

Comment: No error. Tab focus just doesn't show on the `p:inplace` component.

Comment: With the code posted in the solution? What browser are you using?

Comment: Yes, same code. I'm using latest FireFox as browser.

Comment: It is working with the latest Firefox. See https://github.com/jepsar/primefaces-test/tree/so_67901875

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### PrimeFaces 10 and below

Up to PrimeFaces 11, this was not supported out of the box. You could add a node in the `output` facet with a `tabindex="0"` attribute and a register a key down listener to trigger a click on the `display` node if you need this functionality in PrimeFaces 10 and below, like:

```html
<p:inplace widgetVar="myInplace">
  <f:facet name="output">
    <span tabindex="0"
          onkeydown="if(event.key==='Enter'){PF('myInplace').display.trigger('click');event.preventDefault()}">
      Output
    </span>
  </f:facet>
  <f:facet name="input">Input</f:facet>
</p:inplace>
```

### PrimeFaces 11 and up

In PrimeFaces 11 the `display` node will be keyboard accessible by default.

See also:

- https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/7398
- https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/7405/files